# Trigger update other table with count

Tags: mysql, join, triggers, group-by

I have three tables: **contact**, **account** and **account_contact**. account_contact has the relation between the contact and the account.

In the **account** table I have the field **account_contacts** where I have the count of contacts for each account. I can run an sql that updates this value but I want to update it everytime I create or update the contact table.

This is the update sql:

```
update account a 
  left join (
    select ac.account_id as a_id, count(c.id) as contacts
    from account_contact ac
    inner join contact c
    on ac.contact_id = c.id
    where c.deleted = 0
    group by ac.account_id
    ) as n 
    ON a.id = n.a_id
    SET a.account_contacts = n.contacts
```

This is the code I tryed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `contact_new` AFTER INSERT ON `contact`
 FOR EACH ROW update account a set a.account_contacts = a.account_contacts + 1 
where a.id = (select ac.account_id from account_contact ac where ac.contact_id = NEW.id)
```

The answers I found in stackoverflow about trigger have only two tables.

Comment: How exactly did it not work, IE if there was an error message, what was it?

Comment: @Jake: It didn't work as I added a new contact to an account and the numbers of contacts account.account_contacts didn't change.

Comment: @user366329: I read what is online and I search for anwers on internet. I just don't understand what I have to do here otherwise I wouldn't ask. More basic things are asked and answered here without sarcasm.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, done ! This is the code, it wasn't too diferent from the update.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `contact_new` AFTER INSERT ON `contact`
 FOR EACH ROW update account a 
  left join (
    select ac.account_id as a_id
    from account_contact ac
    inner join contact c
    on ac.contact_id = c.id
    where ac.contact_id = NEW.id
    ) as n 
    ON a.id = n.a_id
    SET a.account_contacts = a.account_contacts + 1
```